# finding the next iteration value in newton raphson method

Tags: wolfram-alpha

Is there some easier way to tell wolfram to compute the next approximation using wolfram alpha. I am hoping there is a way to analytically compute this.

[image]

The best I got was: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f(x)+%3D+log+x+%2F+x+-+a;++compute+x_1+%3D+x_0+-+f(x_0)%2Ff%27(x_0)+given+x_0+%3D+1

Comment: WA is a web application, so your question is perfectly welcome here, but I think you might get a more expert opinion on [Mathematica.SE] https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wolfram-alpha-queries

Comment: I would suggest another web application from Wolfram Research: [Wolfram Development Platform — Introduction to Wolfram Language — Things to Try](https://develop.open.wolframcloud.com/objects/wpc-welcome/ThingsToTry.nb). For this kind of stuff I would use _Wolfram Language_ instead of _WolframAlpha_. Something like the following in _Wolfram Language_ would do the trick:
`f[x_] := Log[x]/x - a; NestList[(# - f[#]/f'[#]) &, 1, 3]`

Comment: @jonsca The tag page you linked says "Questions about Wolfram Alpha itself are off-topic."

Comment: @Alex Apparently it does! :) Sorry.